# Django auto-generated unique field failing validation on form edit

Tags: python, django, forms

I am attempting to reuse my create form (EntryForm) for editing a model in Django. My Entry model has a unique slug that is generated on save. This works fine when creating an Entry, but shows the following error when I attempt to edit it:

> Entry with this Slug already exists.

I saw several similar questions, but most were failing to set `instance=` when instantiating the form. I'm pretty sure I'm doing that part correctly.

I've removed other model fields from the code below for clarity.

Here is my model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.title:
            self.title = self.date.strftime('%B %-d, %Y')
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My view:

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_slug):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, slug=entry_slug)

    form = EntryForm(instance=entry, label_suffix='')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=entry, label_suffix='')

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'journal/entry/form.html', {'form': form})
```

My form:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=128, label="Title (defaults to date)")
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Entry
    exclude = ()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is what you need: https://github.com/neithere/django-autoslug/

Comment: If you're generating the `slug` automatically in your model's `save` method, why are you using `slug` in the `EntryForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally figure this out.

The issue was stemming from the fact that I was reusing my create template for the edit form, but forgot to set the form action dynamically depending on which action I desired. So, my 'edit' form was rendering correctly, but actually submitting via the 'create' action.

Thanks to those who commented and to what ultimately led me to debugging the problem, this [handy code snippet](https://gist.github.com/obfusk/208597ccc64bf9b436ed) equivalent to Ruby's `binding.pry`:

```
import code; code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

I did also take @xyres's advice and remove the slug from my form, as it was unnecessary.

New form:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=128, label="Title (defaults to date)")

class Meta:
    model = Entry
    exclude = ['slug']
```

New final line of `edit_entry()`:

```
return render(request, 'journal/entry/form.html', {'form': form, 'entry': entry})
```

Form action:

```
  {% if entry %}
    <form id="entry_form" method="post" action="/journal/entry/{{ entry.slug }}/edit">
  {% else %}
    <form id="entry_form" method="post" action="/journal/new_entry/">
  {% endif %}
```